# Frame.Navigate failing when parameter is given

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, winui-3

When I attempt to send parameters along with Frame.Navigate method it fails with "NullReferenceException".

This is the method with frame.navigate method

```cs
private void remotesList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    string args = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.ClickedItem.ToString());
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RemoteContent),args);
}
```

This is the code on receiving page

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string args = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>((string)e.Parameter);
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or any other way to send arguments with navigate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into this same issue. The problem was that OnNavigatedTo runs after the initialization method (public RemoteContent() in my case). I tried to use the parameter given in the Frame.Navigate inside the initialization method of RemoteContent. Because OnNavigatedTo was called after this, the value was used before it could be assigned.